# how to use $wpdb->prepare to update a custom table

Tags: wpdb, sql

As a noob I dont understand a lot of SQL injections but I need to be save so I have read that I have to use wpdb->prepare to make sure the data is stored correct.

At this moment I use the $wpdb->update() query so I need some help to transform this into an save query with $wpdb->prepare().

```
$wpdb->update('custom_table',
    array(
    'option_1' => 'hello', 
    'option_2' => 2,
    'option_3' => 'world'
    ),
    array('option_name' => 'some name'),
    array('%s','d%','%s')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the [Codex article on `$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows), then you will see that your current usage is correct. The last argument

```
array( '%s', '%d', '%s' )
```

already indicates that there is something like `sprintf/printf` going on in the background.

The `$wpdb->prepare()` method isn't needed for every other method. The ones that need it:

```
$wpdb->query()
$wpdb->get_var()
$wpdb->get_col()
$wpdb->get_row()
$wpdb->get_results()
```

and plain SQL queries like:

```
$sqlQuery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT etc.", /* list of replacements */ );
```

*where the last probably will always get wrapped inside `$wpdb->query()` anyway.*

Comment: @user759235 Then please file an [edit] and add those :)

Comment: couldn't find the edit button...no I have ;-)

Answer (score -2):

If always escaping input like: post, get, request, cookie SQL injection are not possible.
`$input_var=mysql_real_escape_string($input_var);`

or more good this function:

```
function doEscape($str) {
  return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($str)):mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions [shouldn't be used since WP 3.9](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/). The simple replacement for `mysql_real_escape_string` is `esc_sql()`. Even better is making use of the `$wpdb` method [`prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).